# Cordova Plugin - callbackContext.success do not return to application that calls the plugin

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am currently developing a Cordova plugin to call external screen (SDK from .aar) and return the result to Cordova application.

Expected flow of the application:

1. Cordova Application (HTML + JS) calls the plugin
2. Plugin calls an Activity on the SDK (.aar)
3. SDK will show multiple screens (approx 3-5 screen) and send the result (data inside Intent) via broadcast
4. Plugin receives the response from BroadcastReceiver
5. Plugin calls callbackContext.sendPluginResult and callbackContext.success to return data to the Cordova Application. (Plugin
6. Cordova Application get response from the plugin.

My current flow:

1. Cordova Application (HTML + JS) calls the plugin
2. Plugin calls an Activity on the SDK (.aar)
3. SDK will show multiple screens (approx 3-5 screen) and send the result (data inside Intent) via broadcast
4. Plugin receives the response from BroadcastReceiver
5. Plugin calls callbackContext.sendPluginResult and callbackContext.success to return data to the Cordova Application
6. **SDK still shows last screen of the SDK (In the log cat, I can see if the response is recieved by BroadCastReceiver)**

Here is my BroadcastReceiver code:

```
public class SDKResponseReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    CallbackContext callbackContext;    
    public static final String LOG_TAG ="SDKResponseReceiver";
    public SDKResponseReceiver(CallbackContext callbackContext){
      this.callbackContext = callbackContext;
      Log.d(LOG_TAG,"SDKResponseReceiver Creation");
    }
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      String action = intent.getAction();
      Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Broadcast received: " + action);
      String extraData = intent.getExtras().getString("EXTRA_DATA");
      Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Broadcast Data: " + extraData);
      Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Sending Plugin Result.1.");
      callbackContext.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, extraData));
      Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Sending Plugin Result.2.");
      callbackContext.success(extraData);
      Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Sending Plugin Result.3.");
    }
}
```

Questions:

1. Is it not enough only to call `callbackContext.success` or
   `callbackContext.failed` to return to the application?
2. Is there any better way to do this? (My method is using BroadcastReceiver to recieve response from the SDK). Since the SDK is made by third party, it seems difficult to ask them to change the way they send response.

Comment: Calling `callbackContext.success` must be enough (it actually calls `callbackContext.sendPluginResult` so there is no need to call it directly). Perhaps it comes from your plugin and its relationship with your class `SDKResponseReceiver`? How does your plugin look and how/when `callbackContext` is passed?

Comment: The plugin state is on last activity of the SDK.
So the screen is still on the last activity of the SDK, and then send an Intent broadcast to my 'SDKResponseReceiver ', which calling 'callbackContext.success'.

So maybe I need to find a way to switch back to my 'CordovaPlugin'.
Is there any way to do this?